# Access to sessionid from RealmBase object

Tags: java, tomcat, sessionid, jdbcrealm

Is it possible to access to session id from RealmBase.athenticate method? I need it from my custom realm class in order to store into a database additional info associated to the session and retrieve it during the following requests. I'm using Tomcat 8. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No.

Authentication does not require the use of a session, so it's not baked into the API. Authentication is also supposed to be separated from session management, so again it's not baked-into the API.

You might still be able to do this, but it requires some trickery.

1. Write a Valve that uses a `ThreadLocal` containing a Request object.
2. Register the Valve before the `AuthenticationValve` in the valve chain.
3. In that Valve, stuff the user's request into the `ThreadLocal`, then call down the chain.
4. In your custom `Realm`, fetch the object from the `ThreadLocal`.
5. Always remember to remove the request from the `ThreadLocal` after the call chain comes back... even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: Thank you for the response but seems is not working. I've overriden with 2 specific additional class the 2 methods RealmBase.authenticate(String userId, String accessToken) and FormAuthenticator.authenticate(Request request, HttpServletResponse response). There are two different issues: 1) seems that the 2 methods use different threads 2) after some calls the ThreadId is reused and so the ThreadLocal is shared between threads causing overlap of informations. :-( Could you please send me some example?

Comment: I'm not going to write the code for you; it was only a suggestion for what might work. Yes, the threads are re-used... that's why I included step #5 above: it will remove the information that should be private. If you are running into information-leakage, it's because you didn't do step #5 above.

Comment: The authenticator valve is automatically added to the valve chain by Tomcat if none is specifically-configured. You will need to explicitly configure the authentication valve within your `<Context>` and make sure that it is *later* in the valve chain than the one that deals with the `ThreadLocal`.